# Conditional probability : 2-bowl problem

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

I need help with solving this one:

"Bowl I contains eight red balls and six blue balls. Bowl II is empty. Four balls are selected at random, without replacement, and transferred from bowl I to bowl II.

One ball is then selected at random from bowl II. Calculate the conditional probability that two red balls and two blue balls were transferred from bowl I to bowl II, given that the ball selected from bowl II is blue"

(The official answer is: 70/143)

**Update:** Ok, got the answer using p(2,2|blue) = p(blue|2,2)p(2,2) / p(blue).
Turned out to be simpler than I had thought.

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: my attempt involves : p(B1=2,2|B2=blue) = p(B1=2,2)p(B2=blue|B1=2,2) / p(B2=blue) ...  now, p(B1=2,2) I can do, but that leads me nowhere in directly computing p(B2=blue)

Comment: It is true that $P(A|B)=P(A)P(B|A)/P(B)$. But more useful here is $P(A|B)=P(A\&B)/P(B)$. Does this help?

Comment: TonyK: ok thanks, will look into that strategy